Ruby Rails Calendar DST Issue
I am having an issue with Rails code displaying calendar entries off an hour when viewing. The data is correct in the database so I'm sure I'm missing something for the code. I have tried numerous things, any help is greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to Rails and inherited the application
Here is my code and as you can see by the commented out portions, what I have tried. I also can't get it to populate the time zone. I should mention this only needs to be pacific time
  #Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
  #Time.zone_default = Time.find_zone! 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

  def convert_virtual_attributes_to_schedule_object

    zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
    @start_time = Time.parse("#{start_date} #{start_hours}:#{start_minutes}") rescue nil

    #@start_time = Time.parse("#{start_date} #{start_hours}:#{start_minutes} #{Time.zone}") rescue nil
    #@start_time = start_time - 1.hour if start_time.dst? && !Time.now.dst?
    #@start_time = start_time + 1.hour if Time.now.dst? && start_time.dst?

    @end_time = Time.parse("#{start_date} #{end_hours}:#{end_minutes}") rescue nil

    #ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone].parse("start_time")
    #tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
    #tz.parse("start_time").to_datetime

    unless self.schedule # New event
      self.schedule = Schedule.new(start_time, :duration => end_time - start_time)
    else # Changing old event
      self.schedule.start_time = start_time
      self.schedule.duration = end_time - start_time
    end
  end

I have tried using activesupport to set the time zone and also calculations for start time such as:
#@start_time = Time.parse("#{start_date} #{start_hours}:#{start_minutes} #{Time.zone}") rescue nil
#@start_time = start_time - 1.hour if start_time.dst? && !Time.now.dst?
#@start_time = start_time + 1.hour if Time.now.dst? && start_time.dst?


I am not sure if I understood it correctly, but maybe this can help you a bit:
Time.now
# => 2024-04-10 22:58:32.72156 +0200
Time.now.zone
# => "CEST"

Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
# => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
Time.now
# => 2024-04-10 22:58:46.051782 +0200
Time.now.zone
# => "CEST"
Time.now.in_time_zone
# => Wed, 10 Apr 2024 13:58:57.539545000 PDT -07:00

t = Time.parse("2024-04-10 22:45:31")
# => 2024-04-10 22:45:31 +0200
t.zone
# => "CEST"
t.in_time_zone
# => Wed, 10 Apr 2024 13:45:31.000000000 PDT -07:00

